# C++ calling a method from another class

Tags: c++, enums, token, header-files

- I have 2 classes together with their header files called lexer.cpp and lexer.h , token.cpp and token.h
- These are needed to create a compiler. At the moment I'm still doing the lexemes, dividing and reading the Tokens.
- Now I have a method which will read every character I load from the file, and when for example it identifies that it is an integer, it will return a Token (which are the Tokens in token.cpp)

---

**The Problem:**

In token.cpp I have an enum class Token which has all the tokens that can be read by my compiler (coding will be provided below)

Now in

1. Lexer.cpp I have to call this class (enum class Token in **Token.cpp**). In **token.h** I just declared the class name
2. Lexer.h I wrote the name of the method that is to be used in Lexer.cpp

But they are generating some errors.

---

**Error:**
[image: Error]

---

**Code:**

**Lexer.cpp**

```
Token Lexer::getNextToken(char ch)
{
    return Token::tkDigit;
}
```

**lexer.h**

```
#ifndef lexer
#define lexer
#include "token.h"
class Lexer
{
public:

    char ReadChar();
    bool IsDigit (char ch);
    bool IsAlpha (char ch);
    bool IsIdentation (char ch);
    Token getNextToken (char ch);
};

#endif // lexer.h
```

**Token.h**

```
#ifndef token
#define token


enum class Token
{
    tkLetter,
    tkDigit,
    tkPrintable,
    tkType,

    //Literals
    tkBooleanLiteral,
    tkIntegerLiteral,
    tkRealLiteral,
    tkCharLiteral,
    tkStringLiteral,
    tkUnitLiteral,
    tkLiteral,
    tkIndentifier,

    //Operations
    tkMultpicativeOp,
    tkAdditiveOp,
    tkRelationalOp,

    //Params and Calls

    tkActualParams,
    tkFunctionCall,

    //cast and factors
    tkTypeCast,
    tkSubExpression,
    tkUnary,
    tkFactor,

    //Terms and Declarations

    tkTerm,
    tkSimpleExpression,
    tkExpression,
    tkAssignment,
    tkVariableDecl,
    tkFormalParam,
    tkFunctionDecl,

    //Statements
    tkReadStatement,
    tkWriteStatement,
    tkIfStatement,
    tkWhileStatement,
    tkHaltStatement,
    tkStatement,
    tkBlock,
    tkSxl,

};


#endif // token
```

Comment: An aside: The class part of `enum class Token` means that you are always going to have to qualify members as e.g. `Token::tkLetter`. At that point, the `tk` prefix is entirely redundant.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: When you declare an enum with `enum { Foo };` you create a symbol, `Foo`, in the current namespace. `enum class Bar { Foo };` declares `Foo` inside namespace `Bar`. To access the first, you would just write `Foo`. To access the latter, you must always qualify it with the namespace, i.e. `Bar::Foo`. In your example the enums have both a class and a prefix, `Token::tkLetter`. You should remove the prefixes and just call them, e.g. `Token::Letter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move  definition of `enum class Token` from **token.cpp** in header **token.h** **replacing** the definition of the ampty enumeration with the same name and include this header in **lexer.h**

As I said move the enumeration declaration from token.cpp in token.h. Is it clear?

And function getNextToken should look as

```
Token Lexer::getNextToken(char ch)
{
    return Token::tkDigit;
}
```

Comment: I copied everything, but still the same result

Comment: @odoSerebro Use qualified name before each enumerator as for example  Token::tkLetter

Comment: I included all the definitions of the enums in the token.h and also imported it into lexer.h ( enum class Token{};) 

BUT I have a new error in Lexer.cpp now it is saying for that method Token Lexer::getNextToken 

error: prototype for 'Token Lexer::getNextToken(char)' does not match any in class 'Lexer'|

Comment: @ DodoSerebro remove this line from the class definition:   enum class Token{};

Comment: we return to the same error in Lexer.cpp class method Token::getNextToken(char ch) as tkDigit "was not declared in this scope"

Comment: @DodoSerebro This declaration   public enum class Token is invalid. Remove keyword public. Why do you invent each time your own constructions?!

Comment: CHeck now, I've updated my code. And i'm trying to understand why the error is that tkDigit is not declared

Comment: @DodoSerebro I do not see that you did this.

Comment: I tried it afterwards, it says ''Token' is not a class or namespace'

Comment: @DodoSerebro I do not see the updated code and the statement where the error occurs.

Comment: check now... because I can't understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Solved it! The compiler was just assuming it wasn't C++11.. so I had to do some flags in order for me to fix it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

In `Lexer.h` you are using a type (`Token`) of which the compiler (given `lexer.h` dependencies) knows nothing.

Just include the declaration of `Token`, with an `include`

```
#ifndef lexer
#define lexer
#include "token.h"

class Lexer
```

Comment: That solved part of it, but why does the return tkDigit still is NOT declared in this scope? I mean the header file is now included

Comment: Because the items in the enum are defined in the `.cpp` file, which has not been included. Move the definition to `token.h`. As a rule of thumb, if a symbol is to be used in another class, define it in the .h.

Comment: I've copied everything but the result still stayed the same

Comment: My bad, I was thinking of old fashioned C enums, not `enum class`. Since it is part of a class, `Token::tkLetter` (as kfsone had already realized).

Comment: I changed coding in my Original, post to show what there is now.